# Allocated Failure Rates not Adding Up

Tags: probability

A large data set gives the failure rate of vehicles in 5 different Classes. For each of these 5 Classes, there are different road types traveled on (i.e., highway,  Business, residential, urban, suburban, etc.). Most of these road types are contained in multiple Classes, though.
Class 1 consists of almost all highway, and some business;
Class 2 consists of ~75% highway, 15% business, 5% residential, and a few % for two other road types;
The other three Classes consist of various %'s of road types - with Class 5 being a majority of suburban and urban roads.
When moving from Class 1 to Class 5, the change is generally from highway to urban/suburban roads.

- The % of miles driven on different road types within each Class is known (i.e, Class 3 has 54% business roads, 38% residential roads, 5% urban roads, and 3% suburban roads). Similar info is known for the other 4 Classes.
- The % of each Road Class adds to 100% of the road mileage within each Class.
- The overall vehicle failure rate is known for each of the 5 Classes.
- As said, many road types are included in multiple Classes.

I want to estimate the failure rate (FR) for each Road Type.  So, I set up a set of 5 simultaneous equations to solve for the Road Type failure rates.

For example,

0.54*(FR-business) + 0.38*(FR-Residential) + 0.05*(FR-urban) + 0.03*(FR-suburban) =  Overall FR (Class 3)
There are four other equations for each of the other four Classes.

When I solve for the FR's of the Road Types (which is what I want), I'm using standard matrix algebra assuming linear equations.  I'm getting a solution, but it's with NEGATIVE numbers for some of the Road Type FR's.  FR's, though, cannot be negative. A FR of zero would be the lowest possible, meaning no failures.

What am I doing wrong?  The FR for each Road Type is a rate (events/mile), and the overall FR for each Class is a rate (events/mile).  The simultaneous equations should be valid for solving.
Are the results somehow skewed because there is a different number of miles within each Class? The FR of a specific Road Type is the same whether it's in Class 1, Class 2, or another Class.  Seems that each of the Road Types can be solved for.
Also - I am limiting the Road Types to 5, so that there are 5 unknowns to solve for with the 5 equations I have.

I appreciate your comments.

Comment: You did not seem to tell “mathematics” that you want probabilities. Matrix algebra just does what it is supposed to do: give you a solution :-) The most direct way would be to enlarge the equations with side conditions which state that the FRs need to lie in between 0 and 1. However, it might be the case that there is no solution at all. What people usually do in these situations is introducing a sigmoid function, i.e. you may want to solve $\sigma(0.54FRB+...+0.03FRS)=FRcl3$. However, if math is not doing as it’s told to then it usually hints that your mode is inappropriate...

Comment: Or let us phrase it in this way: It's 4 equations in 4 variables and you already told us that there is a solution. That means it is the only solution. Hence, posing additional restrictions would not make sense, it would give you the empty solution set. Therefor, there seems to be no such linear relationship between these different variables... What makes you think that there is such a relationship?

Comment: I would think that there is a solution where all Road Type failure rates are greater than zero because the data is real.  It could be that the previous analysis has an error (and that the Road Type contribution per Class has errors), but it appeared valid.  The trend from mostly Highway Road Type in Class 1 to mostly Residential Road Type in Class 5 lends credibility.  Nonetheless, I have tried to find a solution multiple ways and find only this one solution (with negative failure rate for 2 Road Types, which is impossible physically).

Comment: I do not claim that there is something wrong with the data. I wonder: why so you expect this particular relation to hold true? Why isn't it 0.54*(FR-business)^2 + 0.38*(FR-Residential)^4 + 0.05*(FR-urban)^6 + 0.03*(FR-suburban)^10 = Overall FR or something else (even crazier)?

Comment: The failure rates for the Road Types (which make up each Class) would sum to the overall failure rate for the Class these Road Types belong to.  A simple summing of the failure rates would lend to a linear relationship.

Comment: I cannot 100% grasp what you mean (also party caused by the fact that I do not see the data) but it seems as if you assume that $\sum_{r} P[\text{failure}|\text{ROAD_TYPE}=r] = 1$ which is not at all true. Given a conditional distribution $P[X|Y]$ then we only know $\sum_x P[X=x|Y=y] = 1$ for fixed $y$ but not that $\sum_y P[X=x|Y=y] = 1$ for fixed $x$!